# Selenium - unable to submit comment

Tags: python, forms, selenium, web-scraping, cookies

I am trying to write a script that would allow me to submit comments to a news website programmatically.
I am using Selenium and here is my scrip (with the exact link I am trying to work with):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.delfi.lt/en/lifestyle/earth-day-events-for-the-spring-equinox.d?id=87005127"
driver.get(url)

# Clicking 'I agree' on a cookies banner:
cookies_ok = '//*[@id="c-right"]/a'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(cookies_ok).click()

# XPath list
anon = '//*[@id="comments-listing"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/span'
name = '//*[@id="inputDiv"]/div/form/input'
comment = '//*[@id="inputDiv"]/div/form/div[3]/div/textarea'
button = '//*[@id="inputDiv"]/div/form/div[4]/div[2]/button[1]'

# Click 'Anonymous' -> fill name and comment fields -> press PUBLISH
driver.find_element_by_xpath(anon).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(name).send_keys('name')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(comment).send_keys('comment')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(button).click()
```

Everything works, but when I the last command is executed, I am getting this message on the website:
[image]

"Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser". However, when I follow the same steps myself in browser, there are no issues with cookies.

Any ideas on how to prevent this error?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `undetected chrome driver` https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It still does not work. So bizzare, i tried all the proposed solutions on different computers..

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

This will install the latest chrome browser and your test will run.

You may need to install `webdriver-manager` by using `pip install webdriver-manager`

Comment: This is not a version issue

Comment: Well, I could able to run the above script in my local.

Comment: Does that mean it's a version issue ?

Comment: looks to me, as the screenshot clearly says `the browser doesn't support cookies`.

Comment: If I run the same code in previous version of chrome it would not work ? Selenium does not work like that

Comment: moreover your solution does not tell how to resolve `the browser doesn't support cookies` issue. It just says `Use the latest version`. That's not a solution mate

Comment: Not sure about it, there may be multiple solutions to it.
I found this as a working one.

Comment: I have multiple project setup with different selenium and driver version.. and I am pretty much sure if I run the same code on even 2.53 Selenium it would work

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I am running into the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

You may optimize the code and I assume you have to latest binaries :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.delfi.lt/en/lifestyle/earth-day-events-for-the-spring-equinox.d?id=87005127")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='c-right']/a"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.as-link:first-child")))).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input-name"))).send_keys("denisafonin")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.input-message"))).send_keys("Your comment")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.input-login"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am running into the same issue.. What do you mean by the latest binaries?

Comment: @denisafonin :  you need to have inline binaries for Selenium webdriver, google chrome and chromedriver. If you do not know the compatible version for all of them, I would suggest to get latest from their official web site

Comment: @denisafonin  : Which OS you are working on ?

Comment: Windows 10. I've just pip installed selenium, so that part should be up to date.  I used webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install() suggestion from another comment to update chrome driver. Chrome is also up to date.

Comment: @denisafonin : then I am clueless, Do you mind running your scripts on firefox ?

Comment: I tried and it would stop at the same point - filling name and comment but then it would stop and not even show this cookies message. Publish button would simply not work, regardless if I press it with a mouse or try to trigger it by xpath

Comment: @denisafonin : that publish button does not do anything even if it is pressed manually. I think we can not do much in this scenario. it has to be fixed from product development side

Comment: But it would work just fine if I'm using regular chrome or firefox. However it throws cookies message when trying to automate it with chromedriver, and does nothing when using geckodriver

Comment: @denisafonin : I don't know why it threw in your machine, I ran the same script in chromdriver windows 10 and I did not see any such exception msg

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's worth trying reinstalling chrome/selenium.. ?

Comment: @denisafonin : I think yes. Shouldn't take more than 10 mins though